# Syncing Google Photos to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Google previously had a way of having a Google Photos folder in Google Drive. So that anything say automatically synced into Google Photos would be shown in Google Drive. But recently (2019), they have removed this functionality. Android phones typically sync available photos to Google Photos, but ultimately I would rather have these end up in Google Drive.

What options are there, beyond downloading the files manually from Google Photos and re-uploading them to Google Drive?

Comment: Suggested edit: "beyond downloading the files manually from Google **Photos** and re-uploading them to Google Drive"